# Using .NET 4 Framework with 4.2 micro Framework

Tags: c#, .net

I have run into a problem where I think I need both .NET 4.2 MF and .NET 4 together using Visual C# 2010 Express.  I need to use the Micro framework to control a netduino for it's ADC functions.  .NET 4 is needed because I need to use NI VISA to record the output of my source equipment.  I've tried making two separate projects and adding one of the as a reference to the other, but that did not work.  Does anyone know a solution or work around for this problem?

Comment: Do they actually run on the same hardware? If not, an assembly reference seems a bit strange...?

Comment: No they don't.  But i need the netduino for it's ADC.  If there is a way I can just access the ADC, that would be nice.